# Hide the Left Bar of XLViewer.aspx

Tags: excel-services, excel-web-access-webpart

I've the need to hide the "Edit in Excel" button of XLViewer.aspx of SharePoint 2013. Unfortunately in the organization I'm working is not possible to access to the SharePoint Server, so I cannot retrieve such page in order to customize it. Does anyone help me sending a copy of XLViewer.aspx (SharePoint 2013) or, alternatively, anyone knows a workaround to implement this customization without modify this page?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Attila

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did to hide the breadcrumb navigation on the xlviewer.aspx page. I added the following CSS directly in the page:

```
<style type="text/css">
BODY #s4-mini-titlearea
{
display: none;
}
</style>
```